# Can we use "https" links to get data in iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, https, nsurlconnection, nsurlrequest

iam currently using NSURLConnection class to hit my server and get some data from it. The server link will be something like this http://sample.com/sample/sampleinformation. But, as we know use of simple "http" is not very secure and is vulnerable to attacks. Is there a way in which i can **use "https" links instead of "http"????**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply change the NSURL used in your NSURLConnection to have ["https://"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Secure) at the beginning instead of "http://". That should be enough to signal to the server that you want to encrypt the transmission.

This adds a bit of overhead to your request so don't use it unless it's necessary.

Comment: if i change my url, should i need to make any changes in my code base while trying to get the data from sever ???

Comment: Give it a try, it should work no differently than if you had you http in your URL. iOS handles SSL/TSL just fine.

Answer (score 1):

```
NSURL *jsonURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"your url here",nil]];


NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:jsonURL cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:120.0];
NSData *responsedata = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
NSString* jsonData = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responsedata encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```